# Cannot open a file with json in OpenShift with python

Tags: python, json, openshift

I have a problem with python code in Openshift.

I have a subdomain on my app where I have to open a txt file with json format.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route('/casestudy1')
def cs1():
    json_data = open("cs1.txt")
    data = json.load(json_data)
    ....do my staff....
    return render_template("cs1.html")
```

if I remove the first two lines from `cs1()` the app works perfect. I tried to run flask localy from command line and it works there as well. The `cs1.txt` file is in the same root with the main.py.

**Error:** Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

**Error on log:**

```
json_data = open("cs1.txt")
IOERROR: [Errno2] No such file or directory: cs1.txt
```

**Application root:**

```
-wsgi
  -static
     -css
     -js
  -templates
     -cs1.html
  -main.py
  -cs1.txt
```

Comment: Can you post content of your `cs1.txt` file, and error your getting?

Comment: @Vor I add the error. On the log console I have a simple error 500. Nothing more. As for the file, is a valid json format. I have used it many times and especially, if I run the app localy, it doesn't have any problem.

Comment: this is not very usefull, try to run `Flask` in debug mode `app.debug = True` or put this two lines in try except block and log an error

Comment: @Vor updated with more errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem.

```
import os
json_data = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"cs1.txt"),'r')
```

instead of

```
json_data = open("cs1.txt")
```